# Tensor flow LSTM with a 3x8 matrix of features

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, preprocessor

I am trying to design a python 3 Tensor flow LSTM to work on a data set.
My problem is that the feature set is a matrix - 8 sets of numbers, where each set is 1,2 or 3 numbers. Currently I'm storing the data as a 3x8 matrix where sets that only had 1 or 2 numbers originally have trailing -1 (actual data can never go below 0).

e.g.

```
[
  [447, -1, -1]
  [147, -1, -1]
  [1120, 10, 1111]
  [0, 0, -1]
  [39, 39, -1]
  [2, 0, -1]
  [27, 24, -1]
  [7, -1, -1]
]
is the same as
[447, 147, [1120, 10, 1111], [0, 0], [39, 39], [2, 0], [27, 24], 7]
```

I have got around 90 of these for the time series (that can be extended by about 3 times as many), with around 150 samples.
I know that I need to turn this data into a set of tensors, but as far as I can figure out, using the (nb_of_samples, seq_len, features), I get something like (150, 90, [3x8]).
I don't know how to turn this into a usable set of tensors, or if there is a way to make this a lot easier on myself.

First time posting, so sorry if the answer is a link to an existing answer or I didn't give enough information, but I can't seem to find anything like this by searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier process:
store the features in a single list and keep a separate list to track the names and order of the features. 
So 3x8 turns into 1x14, with no trailing -1 values.